# How can I convert my attachments code into ContentVersion and ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, community

```
    global class CreateContactFrmEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

        String subToCompare = 'Create Contact';

        if(email.subject.equalsIgnoreCase(subToCompare))
        {
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.LastName = email.plainTextBody;
            insert c;
            system.debug('========='+c);

            Task t = new Task();
            t.Status = 'Normal';
            t.Subject = email.fromAddress;
            t.WhoId = c.id;
            insert t;

            // Save attachments, if any
           if(email.textAttachments != null){
                for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

                    attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
                    attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
                    attachment.ParentId = c.Id;
                    insert attachment;
                }
            }


            //Save any Binary Attachment
            if(email.binaryAttachments != null){
                for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

                    attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
                    attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
                    attachment.ParentId = c.Id;
                    insert attachment;
                }
            }
        }

    result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

How would I convert this into Files

Comment: this can help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234575/adding-attachments-in-apex-convert-the-code-to-add-files

Comment: I have tried that but not able to understand how can I do that

Comment: can you also share what did you tried and if you got any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should edit your question and make the changes there not post them as answer anyway you can write the function definition in the function call place your code should look like this

```
global class CreateContactFrmEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
        String subToCompare = 'Create Contact';
        if(email.subject.equalsIgnoreCase(subToCompare))
        {
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.LastName = email.plainTextBody;
            insert c;
            system.debug('========='+c);

            Task t = new Task();
            t.Status = 'Normal';
            t.Subject = email.fromAddress;
            t.WhoId = c.id;
            insert t;

            List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();
            for (Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                ContentVersion contentVersionObj = new ContentVersion();
                contentVersionObj.title = binAttachment.fileName;
                contentVersionObj.VersionData = binAttachment.body;
                contentVersionObj.PathOnClient = '/'+ binAttachment.fileName;
                contentVersions.add(contentVersionObj);
            }
            insert contentVersions;

            List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
            contentVersions = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN :contentVersions];
            for(ContentVersion contentVersion : contentVersions){
              ContentDocumentLink contentDocumentLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    contentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = contentVersion.ContentDocumentId;
    contentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId = c.Id;
    contentDocumentLink.ShareType = 'I'; // Inferred permission
    contentDocumentLink.Visibility = 'InternalUsers';
contentDocumentLinks.add(contentDocumentLink);
            }
            insert contentDocumentLinks;
           }

    result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i just removed this line "contentDocumentLink.Visibility = 'InternalUsers';" 
It was giving me an error (System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Visibility InternalUsers is not permitted for this linked record.: [Visibility])

But after that it works perfectly fine