# How to share an attachment using url?

Tags: apex, attachment, url, contentdistribution

I am new to saleforce and I used the following code to save files to the Attachment object in salesfore:

```
String base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
attach.ParentId = parentId;
attach.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
attach.Name = fileName;
attach.ContentType = contentType;
attach.IsPrivate = false;
insert attach;
```

Now, I need to generate an url by which the files can be shared outside of the salesforce. After some googling,  I found out that it can be done using `ContentDistribution`. And I want to generate the url in the apex class itself. I have refereed to many tutorials and no one them worked for me. So, please anyone can suggest a way to do it or point to a proper tutorial link which explains the process properly that how the shareable url is generated? I used [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/53986/82119) answer and I couldn't figure out what I should add to the `ContentVersionId` field. When I added attachment Id to that field, I got this error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, ContentVersion ID: id value of incorrect type
```

So, How can I share attachments using an url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) is standard Object that stores file in Salesforce and very similar to attachment in the terms of structure. And you need to pass the Id of ContentVersion to create ContentDistribution. So:

1. Instead of creating Attachment, create **ContentVersion** to store the file. However if you need to create only attachment then you need to create a content version as well for the same as here: [Adding attachments in apex, convert the code to add Files](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234575/adding-attachments-in-apex-convert-the-code-to-add-files)
2. After that you can create ContentDistribution using the ContentVersion created in last step: [Is it possible to get a sharing link (to non SFDC users) from 'files'/'content' via apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29037/is-it-possible-to-get-a-sharing-link-to-non-sfdc-users-from-files-content/53986#53986)

Comment: thank u very much. it worked..